# Java ElasticSearach Bool Geo Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to issue an ElasticSearch query using the java api from my application but for some reason i keep getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanBoostQuery     at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.boolQuery(QueryBuilders.java:301)

Below are the current dependencies I have in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.spatial4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>spatial4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
    double lon = -115.14029016987968;
    double lat = 36.17206351151878;

    QueryBuilder fullq = boolQuery()
            .must(matchAllQuery())
            .filter(geoShapeQuery(
                    "geometry",
                    ShapeBuilders.newCircleBuilder().center(lon, lat).radius(10, DistanceUnit.METERS)).relation(ShapeRelation.INTERSECTS));

    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    SearchRequestBuilder finalQuery = client.prepareSearch("speedlimit").setTypes("speedlimit")
            .setQuery(fullq);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = finalQuery.execute().actionGet();
    SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
    if (searchHits.getTotalHits() > 0) {
        String strSpeed = JsonPath.read(searchResponse.toString(), "$.hits.hits[0]._source.properties.TITLE");
        int speed = Integer.parseInt(strSpeed.substring(0, 2));

    }
    else if (searchHits.getTotalHits() <= 0){
        System.out.println("nothing");
    }
```

This is the query I'm trying to run, i've followed the ES docs but can't get any further.  Has anyone tried to run a query like this, or am I going the incorrect route?  I'm tempted to just abandon the Java API and go back to making HTTP calls from Java, but i thought i would try their Java API.  Any tips appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error for me was resolved after i removed the older dependency related to "org.apache.lucene", we need to make sure all the org.apache.lucene dependecies are latest which are at par with the version which contains SpanBoostQuery:

I commented below and it worked:

```
<!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>lucene-spellchecker</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>3.6.2</version>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
```